# Dynamic HTML elements creation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I have a surface on which I put some geometric figures. When I click on each figure, a widget appears and I can add some SELECT elements. 
For each SELECT, when I choose an element, according to a property of the model I create several new SELECT elements inline.

I use $compile to add new elements like:

```
$('#'+id).append($compile(HTMLelement)($scope));
```

Everything is working good, but when I close the widget and open again the dynamic HTML elements created before disappear.

The following image shows the composition of SELECT elements before closing the widget.
[image]

Do someone know how to prevent angularjs to reset DOM elements?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: With Angular, you should keep direct DOM manipulation to a minimum. I would store the object corresponding to the elements in `$scope` and display them with `ng-repeat` directive. Similarly, widget can be toggled by changing the boolean property bound to `ng-show`/`ng-hide` directives.

Comment: You should update your angular scope for it to keep them. Choosing element event could be bind to a function in controller which would update then its scope. Using jquery with angular is not a very good idea. Try to model the things that do jquery with angular.

Comment: If the end-user navigates away from the screen (or in this case "closed the widget"), no amount of storing the HTML on the scope will matter, as the scope will have been destroyed. The only other option is to store the generated HTML in another place, like a service which remains intact for the life of the application.

Comment: I have assumed widget as part of the same view. Otherwise the question becomes unrelated with angular.